# How to add update function to custom property using _RNA_UI

Tags: scripting

How to add update function? I tried this its wrong.

```
pbone = bpy.data.objects[ControleObj].pose.bones[ControleBone]

pbone[ControleName] = min

if "_RNA_UI" not in pbone.keys():
    pbone["_RNA_UI"] = {}

pbone["_RNA_UI"].update({"myControl": {"min":0.0, "max":1.0, "soft_min":0.0, "soft_max":1.0, "update" = FunctionName }})`
```

Comment: You shouldn't change `_RNA_UI`, it's used internally by Custom Properties panel. If you want an update callback for a property, register a bpy.props property: http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.props.html#update-example